# Using a prebuilt shared Library in Android Studio (cmake)

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

I want to use a C++ shared library inside my Android App.
I tried to follow along the `hello-libs` example from Google's NDK samples, but somehow it doesn't work out.

It seems, that my library isn't packed into the APK. All tutorials i found are using `*.mk`-files, but I want to use `cmake`.

This is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# native lib
add_library(native-lib SHARED
            native-lib.cpp)

set(IMPORT_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../jniLibs)

# shared lib
add_library(shared-lib SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(shared-lib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
                      ${IMPORT_DIR}/dynamic/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}/libLibrary.so)
target_include_directories(native-lib PRIVATE
                           ${IMPORT_DIR}/dynamic/include)

# linking libs
target_link_libraries(native-lib
                      android
                      shared-lib
                      log)
```

As soon as I link the `shared-lib` along with the others, I get the following error, when running the app:

```
E/art: dlopen("/data/app/my.package.name-1/lib/arm/libnative-lib.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: library "C:/projects/HelloLibs/app/src/main/cpp/../jniLibs/dynamic/lib/armeabi-v7a/libLibrary.so" not foun
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: my.package.name, PID: 29266
                  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "C:/projects/HelloLibs/app/src/main/cpp/../jniLibs/dynamic/lib/armeabi-v7a/libLibrary.so" not found
                      at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:371)
                      at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988)
                      at my.package.name.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:11)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1690)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2543)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2771)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1432)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5912)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

It looks like the library is not found on the device. Otherwise it looks like the librarie's path is still the one on my local maschine.

Comment: `dlopen("/data/app/my.package.name-1/lib/arm/libnative-lib.so", RTLD_LAZY)` Did you construct that directory? Shouldn't it be `lib/armeabi-v7a`?

Comment: @DanAlbert, no: on device the valid paths under `lib` are **arm**, **arm64**, **x86**, **x86_64**. Don't ask me why.

Comment: @aydinugur Were you able to solve this issue?? I am having the same problem but can't figure out how to solve it..

Comment: I got same problem with my own prebuilt, but with openssl prebuilt it working normal. Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 4):

The prebuilt **libLibrary.so** does not have SONAME. If for whatever reason you cannot rebuild this library with latest NDK, you may try the [patchelf](https://www.mankier.com/1/patchelf) utility to add SONAME to existing binary.

Answer (score 3):

To package the prebuilt library into your APK, you need to manually configure Gradle with the *sourceSets* block to include the path to your .so file. After building your APK, you can verify which libraries Gradle packages into your APK by using the APK Analyzer(Build>Analyze APK...).

```
android {
...
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs 'imported-lib/src/', 'more-imported-libs/src/'
    }
}
```

for more information please see here "[Include prebuilt native libraries](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/gradle-external-native-builds#configure-gradle)"

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use CMake to use shared libraries (.so files). Just place the libraries inside the respective directories in `src/main/jniLibs` directory. Then you can load the libraries directly.

Android studio may show error in the native method declarations but, your app will work fine.

Comment: But how can I use the library inside my `native-lib-cpp`? The shared library has no jni-methods, I want to wrap them inside a second library, written inside Android Studio.

Comment: You can still target_link_libraries it from jniLibs folder, just specify directory

Comment: @DmitriiZ. can you please share the exact arguments of target_link_libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for packing the prebuilt libraries into your APK - linking them to jniLibs.

For example, I don't use direct placement of libraries (because they already exist elsewhere - in my case in docker image with all required prebuilts, SDK, NDK, etc.) but instead of it I just use linking to them to put them in APK. And if such libraries are also needed at build time, cmake can simply uses find_package().

```
    /app/src/main$ tree
    .
    ├── jniLibs
    │   ├── arm64-v8a
    │   │   ├── libCommonAPI.so -> /opt/thirdparty/android-29/arm64-v8a/capicxx-core-runtime/lib/libCommonAPI.so
    │   │   ├── libCommonAPI-SomeIP.so -> /opt/thirdparty/android-29/arm64-v8a/capicxx-someip-runtime/lib/libCommonAPI-SomeIP.so
    │   │   ├── libvsomeip3-cfg.so -> /opt/thirdparty/android-29/arm64-v8a/vsomeip/lib/libvsomeip3-cfg.so
    │   │   ├── libvsomeip3-e2e.so -> /opt/thirdparty/android-29/arm64-v8a/vsomeip/lib/libvsomeip3-e2e.so
    │   │   ├── libvsomeip3-sd.so -> /opt/thirdparty/android-29/arm64-v8a/vsomeip/lib/libvsomeip3-sd.so
    │   │   └── libvsomeip3.so -> /opt/thirdparty/android-29/arm64-v8a/vsomeip/lib/libvsomeip3.so
    │   ├── armeabi-v7a
    │   │   ├── libCommonAPI.so -> /opt/thirdparty/android-29/armeabi-v7a/capicxx-core-runtime/lib/libCommonAPI.so
    │   │   ├── libCommonAPI-SomeIP.so -> /opt/thirdparty/android-29/armeabi-v7a/capicxx-someip-runtime/lib/libCommonAPI-SomeIP.so
    │   │   ├── libvsomeip3-cfg.so -> /opt/thirdparty/android-29/armeabi-v7a/vsomeip/lib/libvsomeip3-cfg.so
    │   │   ├── libvsomeip3-e2e.so -> /opt/thirdparty/android-29/armeabi-v7a/vsomeip/lib/libvsomeip3-e2e.so
    │   │   ├── libvsomeip3-sd.so -> /opt/thirdparty/android-29/armeabi-v7a/vsomeip/lib/libvsomeip3-sd.so
    │   │   └── libvsomeip3.so -> /opt/thirdparty/android-29/armeabi-v7a/vsomeip/lib/libvsomeip3.so
    │   ├── x86
    │   │   ├── libCommonAPI.so -> /opt/thirdparty/android-29/x86/capicxx-core-runtime/lib/libCommonAPI.so
    │   │   ├── libCommonAPI-SomeIP.so -> /opt/thirdparty/android-29/x86/capicxx-someip-runtime/lib/libCommonAPI-SomeIP.so
    │   │   ├── libvsomeip3-cfg.so -> /opt/thirdparty/android-29/x86/vsomeip/lib/libvsomeip3-cfg.so
    │   │   ├── libvsomeip3-e2e.so -> /opt/thirdparty/android-29/x86/vsomeip/lib/libvsomeip3-e2e.so
    │   │   ├── libvsomeip3-sd.so -> /opt/thirdparty/android-29/x86/vsomeip/lib/libvsomeip3-sd.so
    │   │   └── libvsomeip3.so -> /opt/thirdparty/android-29/x86/vsomeip/lib/libvsomeip3.so
    │   └── x86_64
    │       ├── libCommonAPI.so -> /opt/thirdparty/android-29/x86_64/capicxx-core-runtime/lib/libCommonAPI.so
    │       ├── libCommonAPI-SomeIP.so -> /opt/thirdparty/android-29/x86_64/capicxx-someip-runtime/lib/libCommonAPI-SomeIP.so
    │       ├── libvsomeip3-cfg.so -> /opt/thirdparty/android-29/x86_64/vsomeip/lib/libvsomeip3-cfg.so
    │       ├── libvsomeip3-e2e.so -> /opt/thirdparty/android-29/x86_64/vsomeip/lib/libvsomeip3-e2e.so
    │       ├── libvsomeip3-sd.so -> /opt/thirdparty/android-29/x86_64/vsomeip/lib/libvsomeip3-sd.so
    │       └── libvsomeip3.so -> /opt/thirdparty/android-29/x86_64/vsomeip/lib/libvsomeip3.so
    .
```